# Insert text to link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following tag partial

```
%span.tag-label
  = link_to "#{tag}"  , :controller => "searches", :action => "search_tags", :search_type => search_type,
  :tag_type => tag_type, :tag =>"#{tag}"
```

and I pass tags to the partial as collection:

```
= render "shared/tag_item", :collection => @listing.keyword_list, :as => :tag, 
:search_type => "Listing", :tag_type => nil
```

For some reason, I got this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

in my partial.

If I just put plain text on `link_to "text"`  and :`tag =>"text"` then it works. 
Why my embedded text in `"#{tag}"` doesn't work in this case?

Thank you.
**Update** Show error trace:
`endered listings/show.html.haml within layouts/application (148.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 232ms

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
    1: %span.tag-label
    2:   = link_to "#{tag.to_s}"  , :controller => "searches", :action => "search_tags", :search_type => search_type,
    3:   :tag_type => tag_type, :tag =>"#{tag.to_s}"
  <a href="txmt://open?url=file:///Users/app/views/shared/_tag_item.html.haml&amp;line=2&amp;column=1">app/views/shared/_tag_item.html.haml
```

Comment: Show the error trace of where the error is occuring.

Comment: Make sure `link_to "#{tag}"  ,` is actually `link_to "#{tag}",`

Comment: If you just output `url_for(:controller => "searches", :action => "search_tags", :search_type => search_type,
  :tag_type => tag_type, :tag =>"#{tag}")` instead of `link_to..` does that output as expected?

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace, or at least the line number that's generating the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing local variables to your partial, you have to pass the `render` method the key `:locals`.

```
 render "shared/tag_item", :collection => @listing.keyword_list, :as => :tag, :locals => { :search_type => "Listing", :tag_type => nil }
```

Though I have to admit, I would have expected this to give a NameError and not an ArgumentError. Do a search_type or tag_type method exist somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but you don't need to interpolate your `tag` variable. You can just write `link_to tag` and `:tag => tag`.